# Change elements in a class one-at-a-time?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I'm working on a reference project with tooltip notes throughout a text, and I'd like for the text affected by a note to be highlighted when the tooltip is displayed. My current code has a bug where displaying the first note highlights the correct text, but displaying a subsequent note highlights the text from the first note, not its own. I'm new to Javascript so it's likely I made a rookie mistake, but I think the problem is that I'm using `getElementById` which can only work once, but if I should be using `getElementsByClassName` instead, how do I tell it which node to get when? I know `getElementsByClassName` returns the whole array, and I need a way to only return one node at a time. I haven't yet been able to figure it out myself so help is very much appreciated. Below is a pared-down example of my code that demonstrates my problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <style>
        mark {
            background-color: white
        }
        /* now <mark> is only effective at my discretion */
        
        sup {
            vertical-align: text-top;
            font-style: italic
        }
        
        a:link {
            text-decoration: none
        }
        
        a:visited {
            color: blue
        }
        
        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline
        }
        /* these describe the appearance and behavior of tooltips */
        
        a.tooltips {
            position: relative;
            display: inline
        }
        
        a.tooltips span {
            position: absolute;
            width: 70px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background: #000000;
            height: 25px;
            line-height: 25px;
            text-align: center;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        
        a:hover.tooltips span {
            visibility: visible;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            top: 22px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -43px;
            z-index: 999;
        }
        
        a.tooltips span:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-bottom: 8px solid #000000;
            border-right: 8px solid transparent;
            border-left: 8px solid transparent;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        function seeNote() // <mark> is now activated
        {
            document.getElementById("note").style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
        }

        function hideNote() // <mark> is now deactivated
        {
            document.getElementById("note").style.backgroundColor = "white"
        }
    </script>

    <title>Bug Demonstration</title>
</head>

<body>
    Mousing over note <i>a</i> highlights
    <a class="tooltips" href="#"><sup onmouseover="seeNote()" onmouseout="hideNote()">a</sup><span>note <i>a</i></span></a>
    <mark id="note">affected text</mark> as intended,
    <br> but mousing over note <i>b</i> highlights
    <a class="tooltips" href="#"><sup onmouseover="seeNote()" onmouseout="hideNote()">b</sup><span>note <i>b</i></span></a>
    <mark id="note">note <i>a</i>'s text</mark> instead of note <i>b</i>'s text.
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `id` attributes must be unique in the whole document. You have duplicate `#note`s.

Comment: @Bergi I think the OP knows using the same ID multiple times isn't working. *"I'm using getElementById which can only work once, but if I should be using getElementsByClassName instead, how do I tell it which node to get when?"* Also PADetz, you will need to think of a way to tie/relate the anchor tags to your mark tags.

Comment: For the flexible solution: If you use multiple ids (even lame ones like `note1`, `note2`, …), you can give `seeNote` a parameter that you pass the id string of the respective node. An inflexible solution would be to just take the nearest `<mark>` element in the DOM tree to the hovered `<sup>`,

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I saw something similar to my intended effect done on another website and looked at its source; it turns out there's a way to do this without any scripting at all! The whole effect can be accomplished merely with extra styling of the `<a>` elements in CSS, like so:

a. Delete all JavaScript
b. Delete all `<mark>` tags and their CSS and move each `</a>` to replace each `</mark>`
c. Delete `href="#"` from all `<a>` tags
d. Insert this code into the CSS:

```css
/* affected text highlighted... */
a:hover.tooltips {
    background-color: yellow;
}

/* ...but not the superscript letter */
a:hover.tooltips sup {
    background-color: white;
}
```